# Knockout.mapping.fromJSON fails because of ' characters

Tags: javascript, c#, mvvm, knockout.js

I am trying to bind my viewmodel to Knockout as I need to do some clientside action. I've encountered a problem because of a `'` character.

My model has some objects of `SelectListItem` in it, and such object looks like this:

```
{
    "Disabled": false,
    "Selected": false,
    "Text": "Côte d'Ivoire",
    "Value": 59
}
```

Notice the `'` character in the `Text` property: `"Côte d'Ivoire"`.
This character is the issue for everything, as this is how I'm converting the viewmodel into a `ko` viewmodel:

```
@{
    var serializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
    serializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, serializerSettings));
}

@using(Html.BeginScripts())
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var vm = ko.mapping.fromJSON('@Html.Raw(jsonData)')

    </script>

}
```

Notice how I'm wrapping the `@Html.Raw(jsonData)` inside to `'`. I guess this is where the issue is, I'm just not sure how to solve this.

**UPDATE**

Here's the controller method that returns this data:

```
public ActionResult Solution()
{
    using(var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var viewModel = new DetailsViewModel();

        viewModel.Countries = db.Country.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem{
            Value = "" + x.CountryId,
            Text = x.Name
        });

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is this line:

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJSON('@Html.Raw(jsonData)')
```

specifically the part where you're taking your `jsonData` and stuffing it, unescaped, into a JavaScript string, in essence ending up with:

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJSON('{"Text": "Côte d'Ivoire"}')
```

That single quote needs to be escaped, otherwise you break the whole string.  You can either fix this serverside, and escape the string, or you can use a [different mapping method, `fromJS`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#example-using-komapping), and not surround your JSON string with single quotes:

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(jsonData))
```